# Reverting all Xcode settings to their original state

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I got my Xcode into a non-functional state when I can no longer start a search: once I press <kbd>⌘+F</kbd>, Xcode hangs with a spinning pinwheel, and stops responding. Once this happens, my only option is to force quit and restart.

I tried looking for the saved settings in the workspace and project directories, but the recent search options that I am looking to delete appear to be stored elsewhere. I know that I could clear recent searches through the UI, but that would require bringing up the search dialog, which hangs Xcode.

I would like to reset Xcode to its original state. How do I do it without reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: Having same issue, any resolution to this? It's a very hard problem to search for. "xcode search crash" yields incorrect results for example

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is the officially recommended way to delta Xcode 5's preferences, type in Terminal.app:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

That should restore Xcode to the state of its first launch.

(for older versions of Xcode the command was `defaults delete com.apple.Xcode`, i.e. without the `dt` in the middle).

Comment: Although this did not fix my Command+F problem, it did clear out the old settings. I updated your answer to work with the current version of Xcode. Thank you very much!

Comment: it resolved my problem of not indexing files.. i tried with several steps before. Thanks for the post.

Comment: This fixed the problem with my swift files not showing up when I created a new file

Comment: I enter the code but nothing happens !! `xcode 7.1.1`

Comment: Thank u, this fixed my problem where Xcode was crashing on this error `UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[IDE SourceKit Workspace allSymbolsMatchingNames:kind:]:`

Comment: Fixed issue where couldn't make a NEW FILE

Answer (score 23):

Reset all XCode settings from command line by running following commands then restart XCode:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.*
```

Comment: I enter the codes but nothing happens !! `xcode 7.1.1`

Comment: i used this for 8.3.2 and now my default theme is blue-ish

Comment: I needed this for 8.2.1 - it crashes every time I close a project, so this clears them all out and lets me reload the ones I need manually.

Comment: What is "$Home"?

Comment: Path till Root directory

Comment: My Xocde keep hanging all the time, After I run these commands.