# dyld error when trying to run an iOS 8 app on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6, dyld

Trying to run an app locally on a connected iPhone 5 with Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317). The app otherwise works on all other devices, but on the iPhone 5 I'm getting this error immediately after the app launches:

`dyld: could not load inserted library '/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib' because image not found`

I found this relevant Twitter post: https://twitter.com/steipete/status/473620531111919616, and have tried most of the suggestions there including:

- rebooted the Mac & the iPhone 5
- updated iOS to 8.0.2 from 8.0.0
- created a new scheme to run the Release configuration as opposed to Debug
- ensured that the correct command line tools were being used using `xcode-select`

None of the above worked. I only want to do an iOS restore as a last resort. Is there anything else I can try to get this working before we go the restore route?

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting device/if not simulator fixed it. iOS hasn't updated. Really bad !

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything... rebooting phone, rebooting macbook, clean and rebuild, clearing derived project data, switching Xcode versions, reinstalling XCode 6.1.1 from scratch (2.5Gb download), Xcode 5.1, Xcode 6.0, upgrade phone to IOS 8.1.2, clearing all XCode defaults ([Reverting all Xcode settings to their original state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141112/reverting-all-xcode-settings-to-their-original-state)), and even building multiple empty XCode iOS apps with different deployment options (iOS 7.0, iOS 8.0, iOS 8.1).

The only thing that worked for me was to restore the entire iPhone 5 with a full firmware backup.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by deleting the project's derived data.