# Xcode stops autocompleting, UIKit classes not available

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, uikit

The topic has raised several times within the last weeks. Till now I haven't found a proper solution. Is it just a momentary Xcode bug or is there more behind it?

Scenario:

In one of my projects autocompletion has stopped working when I last opened it. Other projects are not affected. It looks kind of reasonable that once this problem is around, I also can't cmd+click the different classes imported by UIKit anymore like `UIViewController` or protocols like `UITableViewDataSource` within this particular project. An error pops up "Symbol Not Found". So in a way, even though it is working fine when running the app, it is just not available from inside the files.

Restarting Xcode, deleting derived data etc. hasn't brought me any further so far.

Any ideas? Or - like mentioned - really nothing else than just a bug?

Comment: It may happen due to indexing. Clear derived data of your project will recalculate indexing.

Comment: Try to reset the xcode default properties

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141112/reverting-all-xcode-settings-to-their-original-state

Comment: @srinivasn The mentioned problem is present just in that one project of mine so it doesn't really look like an appropriate way to me to reset Xcode completely (what could affect other projects in some way too, no?)...

Comment: @Kampai Like I wrote, I already cleared my derived data and also cleaned the project via cmd+shift+k

Comment: Just make it confirm that you have deleted derived data from this path. -> `user>Library>Developer>Xcode>DerivedData`. If you have done already then it may be issue due to cache also.

Comment: @Kampai Yes I did delete the derived data from this path as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which part exactly was the key issue but

- Installing Xcode 6.1
- Downloading iOS 8 libraries & Xcode 6 libraries within Preferences

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting active scheme works for me.
You have to select proper device corresponding to your installed components.
XCode 6.1 has iOS8 primary, so you have to select iPhone6 or Resizable iPhone, if you select iPhone5 it couldn't find it.
(project name>device) on the right of the 'Stop running' button