# Reset Xcode 6.3 to its original state

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Xcode.
Recently Xcode on machine is broken.
I am getting error "Unable to boot up iOS simulator"

I tried lot of steps mentioned on stackoverflow and blogs but couldn't get it working.

I am hoping reseting Xcode will fix the problem. Even after uninstalling and reinstalling, Xcode is having previous state.
Is there any way to reset Xcode along with simulators ?

Comment: I think you solve this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim

Comment: Did you try a solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21141112/335858)?

Comment: I tried both the methods. but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the Xcode.app data from `~/Library/Developer`, which can be done from the command line (when Xcode is not running):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer
```

You will then need to re-download the SDKs and Documentation from with Xcode.  You might also want to check that the Command Line Tools are set-up from Preferences > Locations.

There is no need to reinstall `Xcode.app`, unless it's become corrupt, as nothing should ever write into the app bundle.

You might want to look at `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode` as well, but on my system that folder is empty.

Comment: how to install SDK again ?