# Having issue with Apple TV view in interface builder

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tvos, television

I am developing a TvOS app and having issue with interface builder, when I drag objects like `Buttons`, `labels`, segments and etc... the current view show me nothing!!! only a blank rectangle that shows position and area of that object

[image: Apple TV - Blank rectangle]

When I run the application objects will be shown fine!

[image: Apple TV - Selection box]

What is wrong with the interface builder?

> Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b),
>   OS X version: 10.11.1 (15B42)

At the top of that screenshot there is an error.

> "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited"

Comment: At the top of that screenshot there is an error. "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited". Maybe check what thats about. Restart might solve it.

Comment: Xcode 7.1.1 update - "improves stability and fixes critical issues in Interface Builder, debugging and UI Testing" might be worth updating.

Comment: @sbarow I updated xcode , restart the mac , create new project , but the problem still exist !!!!!!

Comment: I had the same issue after quitting xcode and re-open the IDE solved the issue.

Comment: @Yohan I did , but no success ! It seems I am the only one in this world who faced with this problem !

Comment: Make a new user account and try it there, if it still is the case the problem is in your settings.

Comment: @yene Thanks !!!! It worked but why this happened ? How can I fix my main user ?

Comment: Close Xcode and remove all Xcode settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31719350/279890

Comment: @yene Didn't work !! It seem I have to clean install my mac ! to fix this issue

Answer (score 3):

**Solution :**

I had transferred all my files via Transfer Assistant form old mac to the new one , so I think this might cause the problem ! the final solution was I **created admin new account**  and the problem is gone ! Unfortunately updating to `Xcode 7.1.1` did not any help !

If you face with the same problem be careful backup all data from your current user account.

Answer (score 1):

I get this a lot. I usually just quit out of Xcode and open it again and it will work most of the time.

Comment: Did not work for me !!! I have done many thing , uninstalling , re installing , restart my mac , quit xcode and etc !!! Non of them worked

Comment: File a Radar. Since so many people are getting this they need to up the priority of this bug

Comment: It seems i am the one and only !! There is no similar issue on the internet !

Answer (score 1):

Just update the Xcode to  "7.1.1 (7B1005)", I hope this will solve your problem

I tried to put the buttons on the storyboard its working fine [image]

Comment: I did problem still exist ! I had to change my user account to a new one and then problem solved