# Can't open XCode 8.3.3 without any error or warning

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-sierra, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 on Macmini version 10.12.3 (16D32) from past 6 months and it was working all fine. now today i'm just unable to open xcode at all and it's not even giving any error or warning so i have no idea what's wrong. there is no update in app store for Xcode as well and it's also not being updated recently. i have tried online solutions but still no progress, tries restarting as well. nothing worked. any quick suggestions will be really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: try to download https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3.3/Xcode8.3.3.xip xip and use that instead of download direct from appstore.

Comment: @NitinGohel is it necessary to reinstall the xcode? can't i fix the recent one?

Comment: as you said there is no error no logs so we can't find the issue what it is? so i suggest to do like that i am not sure about other idea coz if we know something then we can fix it

Comment: Sounds like an obscure setting got messed up.  To reset ***everything*** without reinstalling, go into Terminal and [type in these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31719350/981049).