# React native app stopped to work after git pull command

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I've an app developed using React Native, everything was ok at the begin, but at certain moment the app started to raise this error on iOS:
`something went wrong initializing native ReactNativeLocalization`

Now, the only thing that i've did is to delete the project, re-get it from git, execute `npm install`, `react-native link`, `pod update`, `pod install`, and build again(using the .xcworkspace file).

If I install manually ReactNativeLocalization a different error will raise:
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')`

If I install also `react-native-gesture-handler` the will crash at the immediately at the startup

I've tried to pull very old version, but everyone of it do the same errors...

There is so much code, I don't know which code could be useful in this case.

I expect that, after re-pull a working version, the app have no errors.

Comment: In the end I solved simply resetting xCode like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141112/reverting-all-xcode-settings-to-their-original-state)